# echo firstname on laravel

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

I'm trying to echo first_name on the page but I couldn't work it out how.

```
$providerEmail = Auth::user()->email;
  $providerName = Auth::user()->first_name;
    return View::make('account')->with( 'providerEmail', $providerEmail, 'providerName', $providerName);
```

the ()->email bit works, it echos the user email but when echoing first_name it gives me $providerName error (Undefined variable: providerName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clean this up considerably.  Rather than assigning a new view variable for each property of your provider, just send the entire provider model to your view like this.

```
<?php

$provider = Auth::user();

return View::make('account')->with('provider', $provider);
```

Then in your views, you can access the email, name, and other properties just as you would in your route or controller.

**In View**

```
$provider->email
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `->with()`:

```
$providerEmail = Auth::user()->email;

$providerName = Auth::user()->first_name;

return View::make('account')->with('providerEmail', $providerEmail)
                            ->with('providerName', $providerName);
```

Comment: Thanks, just few seconds you replied I saw that I was missing that ->with(). But Thank you.