# Global variable in laravel 4

Tags: php, variables, laravel, laravel-4, global

I was wondering how to do a global variable to save me  few lines of copy and pasting this lines. Array it probably and put them in one variable instead? I want to use this variable in other routes.

```
  $providerEmail = Auth::user()->email;
  $providerName = Auth::user()->first_name;
  $providerSurname = Auth::user()->last_name;
  $providerMobile = Auth::user()->mobile;
```

Answer (score 52):

You can create a global `singleton` within `App::before` event

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Singleton (global) object
    App::singleton('myApp', function(){
        $app = new stdClass;
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // Put your User object in $app->user
            $app->user = Auth::User();
            $app->isLoggedIn = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            $app->isLoggedIn = FALSE;
        }
        return $app;
    });
    $app = App::make('myApp');
    View::share('myApp', $app);
});
```

In any view, use it like

```
if($myApp->isLoggedIn) {
    $myApp->user->email;
    $myApp->user->first_name;
    // ...
}
```

In any controller, you can use

```
$myApp = App::make('myApp');
if($myApp->isLoggedIn) {
    $myApp->user->email;
    $myApp->user->first_name;
    // ...
}
```

Check out [Application Events](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events).

Comment: where can I insert the App::before {code here} line? I mean what file?? Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: found out where, its on the filter.php :) Thanks again for this code!

Comment: First, thank you very much for this solution. But how would I make it globally available to all controllers/models etc. without having to instantiate it every time I need to use it within my controllers?

Comment: @Tim, You are most welcome, in the `view` it's already available globally, you can use `$myApp` to access it from any `view` because of `View::share('myApp', $app);` and from any `controller` you may access it using `app('myApp')` or `App::make('myApp')`.

Comment: I understand. But in every controller I have to make 'myApp'. Do I have no possibility doing that just once and access everything from a variable?

Comment: No possible from `controllers` but from `views` it's available using this approach, but if you instantiate it in your `BaseController` then you may access it using `$this->myApp`, for example, in the `constructor` of `BaseController` you may use something like `$this->myApp = app('myApp') ` and then from child controllers you may use `$this->myApp`.

Answer (score 13):

The best way i've seen is by using a config file.

In your app -> config folder, you create a new file called (for example `settings.php`)

```
 app
     config
         settings.php
```

Then in your configuration file you just created (`settings.php`) you could add:

```
<?php

$setting_data['foo'] = 'bar';
$setting_data['bar'] = 'foo';

return $setting_data;
```

You can then retrieve the config file from your code using:

```
echo Config::get('settings.foo'); // Will echo bar
echo Config::get('settings.bar'); // Will echo foo
```

Answer (score 7):

Globals are bad. No matter of what, don't use global variables, don't think about using global variables, always think about how can you not use them in your code and still have all you need to have. [Here are some reasons](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), and there are lot more.

Instead, use Laravel power to help you:

Enforce login on your routes creating groups of authenticated routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/users/posts', array('as'=>'users.posts.index', 'uses'=>'PostsController@usersPostsIndex'));
});
```

Now you know that every call to your posts will be authenticated, you can just

```
class PostsController extends Controller {

    public function usersPostsIndex()
    {
        return View::('users.posts.index')->
                with('user', Auth::user());
    }

}
```

In your view you'll just have to

```
{{$user->email}}
{{$user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name}}
{{$user->email}}
{{$user->mobile}}
```

If you don't want to write code to send a User instance to all your views, use the magic of Laravel's View Composers, adding this to your filters.php or creating a composers.php file:

```
View::composer(array('users.posts.index','users.posts.edit'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('user', Auth::user());
});
```

And this is now how your views can be used now:

```
class PostsController extends Controller {

    public function usersPostsIndex()
    {
        return View::('users.posts.index');
    }

    public function usersPostsEdit()
    {
        return View::('users.edit.index');
    }

}
```

Because Laravel will automatically inject `Auth::user()` in those views as `$user`.

Answer (score 5):

I like the `View::share` method.

Add the following in *app/controllers/BaseController.php*

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {       
        $name = 'jack';    
        View::share('user', $name); // Share $user with all views
    }
}
```

and now `$user` will be available to all your views.

References:
[Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views), [blog post](http://atomicplayboy.net/blog/2013/06/25/global-view-variables-in-laravel/)

Comment: still isn't working for me. Am I missing something? It says "undefined variable"

Comment: You must be, it works and is in the official docs. Make sure you've added `View::share('myvar', 'myvalue');` in the controller, and then in your view make sure you use `$myvar`.

Answer (score 1):

*I also gave you the same answer in another question you asked, you did not respond. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890823/echo-firstname-on-laravel)*

There is no reason to have a separate variable for each property of your `$provider` model.  Simply save the entire model to a variable like this.

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    $provider = Auth::user();
}
```

This would generally be done in a route like this.

```
Route::get('/provider/page/example', function()
{
    $provider = Auth::user();

    return View::make('name.of.view', ['provider' => $provider]);
});
```

After having done that, you can access the different properties in of the `$provider` in your views like this.

```
<p>Your email address is: {{$provider->email}} and your first name is {{$provider->first_name}}</p>
```

Another option is to use a controller and set this variable only once in the controller, making it accessible from all views using `View::share()`.

```
class ProviderController extends BaseController {

    protected $provider;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->provider = Auth::user();

        View::share('provider', $this->provider);
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('some.view.name');
    }
}
```

After having done just this, you can use the `$provider` variable in your views as shown above using things like `$provider->email`.  You can also use it elsewhere in the controller by using `$this->provider`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object to do that.

Create a `provider` object with those properties, `email`, `name`, etc and instantiate it and set the properties values, like:

```
$provider = new Provider();

$provider->email = Auth::user()->email;
```

And then you save the object in your session:

```
$_SESSION['provider'] = $provider;
```

I'm not familiar with Laravel and I don't know if it's a good practice to work directly with the `Auth` object but a simpler solution would be:

```
$_SESSION['provider'] = Auth::user();
```

Also be aware of working with sensitive information on your session :)

Comment: The only sensitive information there is for now is the users email address.

Comment: You should take care with your session information, if you really need it stored, do it. My sessions store the user `id` and when I need it, I request it from database.