# laravel4 passing variable from constructor to view

Tags: laravel-4

I got an `$inbox_unread` variable store in the master page.
I do not want each of function assign the `$inbox_unread`, how do I make it in the constructor?

I had tried

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
    $this->layout->inbox_unread = '123';
}
```

However, it does not work. All my page have to get this variable except login page. How do I achieve this with clean and good practise?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try with a View Composer. http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

Comment: Can you show me solution how to implement it in route.php, controller, and view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code at `App::before` located in `./app/filters.php`:

```
Config::set('myvar', array('key' => 'value'));
```

Now **anywhere** in your app you can retrieve it as `Config::get('myvar.key')`.

If you were to do the following at the same location:

```
View::share('myvar', 'value');
```

Then you'll have `$myvar` available in all your **views**. You can also do:

```
View::share('myvar', array('key' => 'value'));
```

And retrieve as `$myvar["key"]`.

Comment: Sorry for didn't make the things clear, my inbox_unread's value is get from a Model. Inbox::unread();, from your answer, it more to preset value for me.

Comment: You can use your model also in `App:before`. Please check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952572/global-variable-in-laravel-4