# How to define a global variable in Laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel, global-variables

I use to develop with Drupal. In Drupal there are global variables such as $user or $_view, so you can use these in different modules. I wonder how can I make something like this in Laravel, after the user log in, I can use the global $user in different controller.Except using session is there any other ways to implement this one? Thank you.

Comment: Google says: `About 16,500 results (0.22 seconds)`

Comment: Global variables are bad. There is often a better way. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variable in laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952572/global-variable-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 0):

For most constants used globally across the application, storing them in config files is sufficient. It is also pretty simple

Create a new file in the app/config directory. Let's call it constants.php

In there you have to return an array of config values.

```
return [
    'langs' => [
        'es' => 'www.domain.es',
        'en' => 'www.domain.us'
        // etc
    ]
];
```

And you can access them as follows

```
Config::get('constants.langs');
// or if you want a specific one
Config::get('constants.langs.en');
```

And you can set them as well

```
Config::set('foo.bar', 'test');
```